# Appropriate data structure for JSON with multiple key pairs

Tags: javascript, c#, json, data-structures, json.net

I am trying to find a suitable C# data structure for:

```
data: [ 
       {A: <V>},
       {A: <V>, B: <V>},
       {A: <V>, B: <V>, C: <V>},
       {...}
      ]
```

Where A,B and C are string keys and V is a value of *any* type.

The reason for this is because I am passing a Javascript object from the frontend that looks like:

[image]

And deserializing it, changing some of the fields and re-serializing it back.

e.g:

```
var data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Object>>(JSObject);
```

I am struggling on finding a data structure that involves multiple dictionaries that can be re-serialized back into JS easily.

Comment: i think you should add java script too in question's tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A type of `List<Dictionary<string,object>>` should allow you to deserialize from JSON, make any changes required, then re-serialize back to JSON without too much difficulty.